# Change the Action from Href to Onclick Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Html a tag which has a href attribute, and this a tag doesn't have any class or id, but its parents has, but id of parent elements are never same [it's a dynamic content]. i want to remove the href attribute and apply onclick event to it. the value of onclick should be same as of href. i have written a jquery code but its changing only first one. note that i am not constructing this a element dynamically. i can only change its attribute.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="AUDITOR_ASSIGNMENTS_field__div">    
<a aria-label="Open Assignments" href="javascript:getmlov(98,22,2)">Click Me</a>
</div>    
<div id="_1__AUDITOR_ASSIGNMENTS_field__div">    
<a aria-label="Open Assignments" href="javascript:getmlov(99,21,2)">Click Me</a>
</div>
<div id="_3__AUDITOR_ASSIGNMENTS_field__div">    
<a aria-label="Open Assignments" href="javascript:getmlov(102,13,1)">Click Me</a>
</div> 
</body>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#AUDITOR_ASSIGNMENTS_field__div a').each(function() {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $(this).attr('onclick', href)
         .removeAttr('href');
  });
```

**Jsfiddle** 
http://jsfiddle.net/d2vL6/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 $("[id$='AUDITOR_ASSIGNMENTS_field__div']").find('a').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('onclick', href)
     .removeAttr('href');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d2vL6/1/)**

Comment: try using `$(this).prop('onclick', href)`;

Comment: i have modified the code and it works fine, only problem is i dono how to call that function which is stored in string href.  
$("[id$='AUDITOR_ASSIGNMENTS_field__div']").find('a').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        href = href.split(":")[1];
        //$(this).attr('onclick', href +'; return false;')
         $(this).removeAttr('href'); 
         $(this).click(function(){
             href;
         });
  });

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution

```
  $('div a').each(function() {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     $(this).attr('onclick', href)
       .removeAttr('href');
  });
```

Comment: I think this should work $(this).click(href)
         .removeAttr('href');